# How to mass update in MongoDB after corruption

Tags: mongodb

I upgraded Wekan from 0.48 to 0.95.  It looks like what happened in Mongo is that it took the checklist collection from one containing a nested list of items and split it out into a new checklistItems collection.  It appears to have copied the data correctly- except that instead of copying each item's title, it copied the checklist title to each list.

I started with this in wekan.checklists:

```
{
  "_id": "z329QEDfjsuQcxz7E",
  "cardId": "TBgz6gMGCcn9XNPSW",
  "title": "A list",
  "sort": 0,
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2018-05-09T22:20:50.537Z"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "_id": "z329QEDfjsuQcxz7E0",
      "title": "Do some stuff",
      "isFinished": false,
      "sort": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "z329QEDfjsuQcxz7E1",
      "title": "Do some other stuff",
      "isFinished": false,
      "sort": 1
    }
  ],
  "userId": "YndMrPQ5XhZTTKD2S"
}
```

and wound up with the following in wekan.checklistItems:

```
{
  "_id": "RADPEu4nhr9PgwPHH",
  "title": "A list",
  "sort": 0,
  "isFinished": false,
  "checklistId": "z329QEDfjsuQcxz7E",
  "cardId": "TBgz6gMGCcn9XNPSW"
}
{
  "_id": "Guy3aaJL4WLJQjzRX",
  "title": "A list",
  "sort": 1,
  "isFinished": false,
  "checklistId": "z329QEDfjsuQcxz7E",
  "cardId": "TBgz6gMGCcn9XNPSW"
}
```

and this in wekan.checklists:

```
{ "_id" : "z329QEDfjsuQcxz7E", "cardId" : "TBgz6gMGCcn9XNPSW", "title" : "MVP", "sort" : 0, "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-05-09T22:20:50.537Z"), "userId" : "YndMrPQ5XhZTTKD2S" }
```

Is there a quick query to go back through my original wekan.checklists and update the titles in wekan.checklistItems?  I note that the checklistIDs stayed the same but the card id's are different- I can of course load the old wekan.checklists collection into my current (upgraded) db to query against.

Comment: So what is the issue exactly? Is it that within each array the `"title"` value is only **ever** meant to appear **once**? Or within the other collection with the same rule or by the `checklistId`, which is notably missing from the array entries? It's really not clear what you are asking here as "wekan checklists" isn't likely to mean anything to the audience you are addressing the question to. If you could be more specific about what exactly needs to happen, then you might actually get a reasonable response.

Comment: No.  The issue is that the checklist title was cloned into the "title" field for each checklist item- so now every item in a checklist has the checklist title as its text.  In this case, the checklist should appear entitled "A list" with items "Do some stuff" and "Do some other stuff".  However, post-upgrade it appears entitled "A list" with items "A list" and "A list".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix: load your old db.checklists into db.checklistsOld (I used `mongoimport -d wekan -c checklistsOld ~/checklistsOld.bson`, where `checklistsOld.bson` held my backup from before the upgrade.  Use the following script in Robo3T:

```
db.checklistsOld.find({}, {"_id": 1, "items.title":1, "items.sort": 1 }).forEach( (list, i, lists) => { 
  var checklistId = list._id;
  list.items.forEach( (item, j, items) => {
      var sort = item.sort,
          title = item.title;
      db.checklistItems.update({"checklistId": checklistId, "sort":sort}, {$set: {"title": title}} );
  });
});
```

Depending on how many items you have, you may need to adjust  "shellTimeoutSec" in Robo3T (https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/wiki/Robomongo-Config-File-Guide)